# "Facebook Page: Not found for..." when sharing a link on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Whenever I share a link to my webpage on my facebook page, an "i" icon appears and when I click it I get a message that no facebook page is found for my link.

Any idea what is going on and how to fix this?

[image: Facebook Page: Not found for]

Answer (score 3):

This dialogue is called [Context button](https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/638848173163436). You should verify your domain and link your page with it. You can do it inside Business Manager, [see instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification)

Changes take usually several days to propagate information to context button dialogue.